# Open Facebook app with specific post from Android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created an app that gets the news feed from Facebook and displays it.  I want to enable users to comment and like from within my app, but I couldn't find any API for that.  I did find a custom URL scheme for Facebook: fb://post/{postId} which I'm trying to use.  For each post, I get the post Id and create a link in a textview on Android pointing to that URL.  I printed out the URL and this is an example: fb://post/47526370263_10152072729085264

likes is a TextView in my Facebook adapter with the text being the number of likes a post got.  I want this view to contain a link to Facebook's app which will open that specific post.

```
String linkToPost = "fb://post/" + status.getId();

likes.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + linkToPost + "\">" + status.getLikeCount() + " like</a>"));
```

When I click on the link in my app nothing gets opened.  How do I enable people to view/post comments/likes from within my Facebook News Feed app?

Comment: Is the returned post id (using graph api) is the same id you found when you hover with mouse over the post time (using pc browser)? In my case they are different and when I try to open the post using your approach it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw a related answer after I posted this.  The solution is to do:

```
likes.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: can you please explain your answer how can i open specific post form my android app